# Получение данных запроса на jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, get

Добрый день.

Существует такой `div`:

```
<div id="addform" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Туда нужно загрузить данные файла page_edit.php с GET запросом **edit_id: id**. 
Написал такой код:

```
$('ul.Pagelist li i.edit').click(function() 
{
    var pageid = $(this).attr("id"); //тут хранится id редактируемой данных
    var mod_page_edit = $("#addpage_form"); //сюда загружаю ответ GET запроса
    var img_loading = $("#loading"); //картинка "Loading.."

    // Показываю gif анимацию Loading..
    img_loading.fadeIn();

    //загружаю данные файла
    $.get("/page_edit.php", {
        edit_id: pageid
    }, function(data){
        //вставляю ответ запроса в блок #addpage_form
        mod_page_edit.html(data, function() {
            mod_page_edit.slideDown(150); //показываю блок
            img_loading.fadeOut(); //убираю картинку загрузки
        });       
    });

});
```

- Результат: Loading...

Файл `page_edit.php` (допустим):

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

Как решить данную задачу? 
Спасибо.

Comment: В консоли ошибок нет?

Comment: @Zhukov Roman, никаких ошибок!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Метод .html(), не имеет как таковой callback-функции. Вы же её создали и пытаетесь произвести там какие-то действия. Решение простое - убираем эту искусственно созданную callback-функцию и радуемся, что всё заработало:

```
mod_page_edit.html(data);
mod_page_edit.slideDown(150); //показываю блок
img_loading.fadeOut(); //убираю картинку загрузки
```

Comment: эх... черт побери! как же я додумался до этого :DD. Благодарствую! Спасибо.

Comment: А почему тогда ответ не отметили как правильный?

Comment: @dekameron,  черная магия!! я нажимал, по дороге кто то отменил запрос 0_o

Comment: @Maqsood :D